# VBA MS-WORD load all the yellow highlighted texts in variable array

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, highlight, information-extraction

I would like to run a macro that would extract all the yellow highlighted text of the document and pass all those highlighted text into an array variable.

I found this link: [How to perform a selective extraction of text highlighted in yellow from an MS Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075067/how-to-perform-a-selective-extraction-of-text-higlighted-in-yellow-from-an-ms-wo)

but the solution proposed does not work and is not exactly the same.

So basically the logic would be:

look up all the document
count how many highlighted pices of text there are

```
Dim CountYellow as integer
Dim HltText as variant
'i dont know how to do this next:
countyellow= number of highlighted texts
redim HltText(1 to countyellow)
for i=1 to countyellow
'I dont know how to do this next:
FIND THE NEXT YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED TEXT
HltText(i)= HIGHLIGHTED TEXT
next i
```

Thanks a lot

PS; after I re-read my question I would like to add here for clarification. the text would be something like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **THIS TEXT IS YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED** consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur iaculis vehicula arcu, accumsan facilisis eros sagittis sed. Duis sit amet diam sit amet magna pharetra molestie. Cras sagittis lacus non tortor accumsan accumsan commodo at mi. Ut ipsum nunc, suscipit at elit quis, auctor rutrum diam. Mauris vel dictum dolor. Quisque **THIS SECOND TEXT IS YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED** porta a purus in sodales. Pellentesque accumsan ac tellus a molestie. Duis tempor sapien enim, eu THIS **ANOTHER TEXT AS WELL IS HIGHLIGHTED** sollicitudin turpis volutpat sit amet. Ut libero dui, dapibus in vulputate vitae, aliquet vel turpis. Donec nec congue est. In enim turpis, scelerisque id condimentum ac, porta quis tellus.

where then:
HltText(1)="THIS TEXT IS YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED"
HltText(2)="HIS SECOND TEXT IS YELLOW HIGHLIGHTED"
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Sub Highlights()
'
' Highlights Macro
'
Dim rng As Variant
Dim strResults(1000) As String
Dim intIndex As Integer

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wordapp.documents.Open "C:\filename.docx"
    wordapp.Visible = True

Set rng = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Find.Forward = True
rng.Find.Highlight = True
rng.Find.Execute

intIndex = 0
Do While rng.Find.Found = True
    Debug.Print (rng.Text)
    strResults(intIndex) = rng.Text
    rng.Find.Execute
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: thanks. it works. It looks like you forgot the intindex=intindex+1 within the loop but i got that. it works perfectly. thanks a lot. From that on I can start my more difficult task of using the words of the array (yellow ones) to look for those words in the rest of the document where they might be followed by a reference number. thx again

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post another alternative solution not involving FIND using characters.

```
Dim YellowWord(1 To 100) As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer  'counter
i = 0

With Selection
.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
While (ActiveDocument.Range.End - 1) > .Range.End
strText = ""
' mark first character of the current word
.MoveRight Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
If .Characters(1).FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = m_lngFindColor Then
Do
' save charcater
strText = strText & .Text
' next character
.MoveRight Unit:=WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
Loop While .Characters(1).FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = m_lngFindColor And ((ActiveDocument.Range.End - 1) > Selection.Range.End)
Debug.Print strText
i = i + 1
YellowWord(i) = strText
Debug.Print "YellowWord(" & i & ")= "; yellowWord(i)
End If
.Move WdUnits.wdWord, 1
Wend
End With
```

works wonderfuly.

take care that the user do not use any other yellow. I suggest to include a button for highlight in the specific vbyellow color. You know what I mean.